# Zeppelin helium package visualization tools not visible on UI

Tags: apache-zeppelin, helium

apache zeppelin helium packages have been enabled but it does not give visualization icons/options on notebook. What should i do?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Zeppelin 0.7.3 or lower.

Helium doesn't work in "branch-0.7"

https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/afa19f8781da1825fd341ba1578302df523e64c61e01520bdb52df70@%3Cusers.zeppelin.apache.org%3E